# Avoid model repetition on components state initialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to the React application/typescript thing. I just want to ask about on how to make a shortcut declaration of an object during component's initial state.

For example, I have here:

```
export interface Employee {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    age: number
}

class ComponentA extends React.Component<any, State> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employeeA: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                age: 0
            },
            isActive: true
        }
    }
...
}

class ComponentB extends React.Component<any, State> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employeeA: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                age: 0
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

As you can see `employeeA` and `employeeB` of type `Employee` is getting repeated in each component. I think the disadvantages on this approached is that whenever the `Employee` has changed properties and you need to update each of these component that referenced the `Employee`. I'm thinking of creating one `init` method assigned to the employee state, example `employeeA: employeeInit()` which encapsulates the initial value. Any thoughts?

Comment: Like you suggest, a method, like `employeeInit`, which creates a default empty employee would be appropriate in this case! In addition, if both components are referencing the _same_ employee, the employee should only be declared in one component and then should be passed to other components via props, context, or a global state store like redux. If the components are referencing different employees, then what you have is fine.